# How to scalar multiply array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Write a method scalarMultiply which takes as input a double[] array, and a double scale, and returns void. The method should modify the input array by multiplying each value in the array by scale.
. Question to consider: When we modify the input array, do we actually modify the value of the
variable
array
?

Here is what i did until now, but i dont know what i did wrong because it still is not working.

```
public class warm4{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    double[] array1 = {1,2,3,4};
     double scale1 = 3;    
    }
 }
   public static void scalarMultiply(double[] array, double scale){
     for( int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
     array[i] = (array[i]) * scale; 
     System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: you're never calling the `scalarMultiply` method

Comment: @Tyler That's an answer.

Comment: You have 5 `{` and 6 `}`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never calling *scalarMultiply* and the number of the brackets is incorrect.

```
public class warm4{

  public static void main(String[] args){
     double[] array1 = {1,2,3,4};
     double scale1 = 3;    
     scalarMultiply(array1, scale1);
   }

   public static void scalarMultiply(double[] array, double scale){
       for( int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
       array[i] = (array[i]) * scale; 
       System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

You're never calling the `scalarMultiply` method.

Comment: Also he should pay attention to `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is OK. But you must call it from your `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double[] array1 = {1,2,3,4};
    double scale1 = 3;    
    scalarMultiply(array1, scale1);
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah thank you! im new to java, didnt know that we had to call it x). thanks again